How do I revert back to webpack builde in Angular 18?
I am working with Angular 18 for my project which uses esbuild to build the project bundles. I want to switch to using webpack as my bundler. I don't really have code to show because I don't know what I need to do. I tried messing around with @angular-devkit/build-webpack package but trying to use it just confuses me more. There's no article etc with clear instructions on how to achieve this. What is the simplest root to getting this done?

Is there a specific reason for reverting back?

@MikeOne Yes. We have a large project and we want to ultimately compare bundle size and performance. The final goal is to have a fast bundler for dev environment and efficient bundler for production.
